# How to solve google collab cuda malloc failed error?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, yolo

I am running yolo v3 custom object detection for my project.But it is giving error when I tried to run my custom object detection.I am using windows 10 chrome browser.I need help to solve this error.

Thanks in advance.

This is the command that I am trying to run:

```
!./darknet detector train "/content/gdrive/My Drive/darknet/obj.data" "/content/darknet/cfg/yolov3.cfg" "/content/gdrive/My Drive/darknet/darknet_53.conv.74"
```

[THIS IS THE ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62057.png)

Comment: Not a real solution, but worth a try... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54857673/yolo-3-assertion-0-failed-error-not-crlf-error

Comment: @zypro Is image size should be same for all images?Means My image size varies from 200x352 to 1080x1900.Right now my parameters are like this: batch=1
subdivisions=1
# Training
# batch=24
# subdivisions=8
width=416
height=416

Comment: Sorry. I'm no yolo expert.

Comment: @zypro Thank you for your help.The issue is solved when google colab assigned me full resources.Now I am training my own yolo custom object detection.

Comment: you can answer your own question and then "close" it but accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved when google colab assigned me full resources.Now I am training my own yolo custom object detection.

Comment: what does it mean: "google colab assigned me full resources"? is there any limitation in google colab notebook? how to setup this config to have full access?